# PyCharm не создаёт папку venv

Tags: pycharm

Недавно была такая проблема с Пайчармом: при создании нового проекта создавались лишь файлы `.gitignore` да `pyvenv` и папки `.idea`, `Lib` и `Script`, а `main.py`. Я добавил в качестве локального интерпретатора системный (System Interpreter), и после этого возникла обратная ситуация: `main.py` добавился, а остальные ранее перечисленные файлы и папки, кроме `.idea`, перестали создаваться.

Что можно сделать, чтобы все эти папки и файлы создавались вместе с `main.py`?

Answer (score 1):

В момент создания нового проекта открывается диалоговое окно, там есть возможность выбрать *расположение проекта*, а также, если открыть вкладку **интерпретатор проекта**, можно выбрать либо *существующее виртуальное окружение* либо **создать новое**. Может быть у вас выбран пункт выбрать существующее или этот параметр вовсе не настроен?

Comment: А можно ли в пайчарме в уже давно созданном проекте как-нибудь посмотреть, как я какие настройки я выбирал в диалоговом окне?

Comment: @OlegShakespear, к сожалению, не смогу ответить на ваш вопрос, так как давно работал в PyCharm, перешел на VSCode:) Мб завтра гляну на работе, думаю в настройках проекта что-то такое есть, нужно покопаться.

Comment: @OlegShakespear, нашел настройки в Run->Edit Configuration->Environment. Мб поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - создать виртуальное окружение самостоятельно.

Чтобы создать виртуальное окружение, необходимо перейти в директорию с проектом и выполнить команду:

```
python -m venv venv
```

Далее необходимо активировать виртуальное окружение командой

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Если активация прошла успешно, то в командной строке появится префикс `(venv)` перед путем к директории

Comment: Это надо делать через cmd или терминал внутри самого пайчарма? Просто я сделал через cmd, и там появился префикс (venv), затем открыл сам проект, и там в терминале этого префикса нет